can't running tester login with cypress
when I write a script like this the output results on cypress are not running "timed out retriying after 4000ms: expected to find element: a, but never found it"
describe('Login with inputs', () => {
    it('visit the website', () => {
        cy.visit('http://zero.webappsecurity.com/login.html')
        cy.url().should('include', 'login.html')
  });

it('should fill username', () => {
    cy.get('#user_login').clear()
    cy.get('#user_login').type('username')
});

it('should fill password', () => {
    cy.get('input[name="user_password"]').clear()
    cy.get('input[name="user_password"]').type('password')
});

});

only managed to log in with the website.
for should fill username and password cannot be read successfully.
